# (Unity) To remove from a Transform array

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
    public Transform[] spawnPoints;
    void Awake()
    {
        spawnPoints = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
    }

    public void Spawn()
    {
        GameObject enemy = GameManager.instance.objectManager.Get(GameManager.instance.objIndex);
        enemy.transform.position = spawnPoints[Random.Range(1,spawnPoints.Length)].transform.position;
       enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().Init(GameManager.instance.spawnData[GameManager.instance.level]); 
    }
```

---

I made a monster be summoned from a specific location.
I want to create a function that prevents monsters from being created in that location when destroying a specific object, but I tried Transform.RemoveAt(0) and it was impossible.
Is it impossible to remove elements from an array in the form of Transform[]?

My Unity skills are very rudimentary.
I tried Transform.Remove(0).
But, it impossible

Comment: There are a few things wrong there. For example why is randoming from 1 to the length of the array? An array starts at 0 and the actual number of elements is length - 1. Also since you're spawning randomly, don't you want the previously used spawn point to disappear? Third, why do you always want to remove at 0? (Again conflicting with the randoming).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean

```
spawnPoints.Remove(0);
```

No, it is "impossible" to remove anything from the beginning of an array, but there are numerous more or less lazy vs performant ways to do this, like:

```
spawnPoints = spawnPoints.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Another, perhaps better way, would be to use a List instead:

```
 public List<Transform> spawnPoints;
 void Awake()
 {
     spawnPoints = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>().ToList();
 }
```

Then you will be able to do what you tried in the first place:

```
spawnPoints.Remove(0);
```

Note that a List won't have the "Length" property. It is called "Count" instead.

Comment: You are correct, but it won't apply to the OP's code. He is using random spawn points so Removing `0` will always remove the first from the list, not the one he already used. Or so it seems.

Answer (score 0):

First off, use lists.

```
public List<Transform> spawnPoints;
```

You can use `Start` or `Awake` or the Inspector to populate them. (I recommend the Inspector if you're new to coding which seems to be the case)

```
Because you use random points, you need to remember what index you used inorder to remove that specific one. Here is how: 

public void Spawn()
{
    GameObject enemy = GameManager.instance.objectManager.Get(GameManager.instance.objIndex);
    int posIdx= Random.Range(0,spawnPoints.Count-1);
    enemy.transform.position = spawnPoints[posIdx].transform.position;
    enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().Init(GameManager.instance.spawnData[GameManager.instance.level]); 
    spawnPoints.RemoveAt(posIdx)
}
```

I added a local variable to "remember" the transform that you used, then I removed it from the array.

Comment: It should be Count instead of Length. There could be something wrong in the end since this keeps removing items, so when the list runs out, posIdx will get 0 but the list is empty so it will break. You could restore the previously removed item.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to adjust after the copy paste. The design is strange indeed. But it might be a list for the current level like objectives. Maybe.